# Need to pull data from remote sqlite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, http, flask

I have my sqlite3 database in linux machine. And I would like to pull data from this database to my windows machine in a GUI fashion.

I haven't finalized on the design yet (so no code to provide).
I am contemplating on using Flask for windows which will talk to HTTP server in linux machine. This server makes connection to the database and provides data to respective client.

I am also rather new to GUI. Is there any loophole in this approach? Am not planning on anything exhuberant. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is not a server-based database, but rather it is a file-based database, i.e., it is not designed to be accessed over the server, but only to save the data locally.

I would change the design and use another server-based database (MySQL, PostGreSQL, etc.).

If you really cannot use anything else, and want to access it Sqlite database over network, I would expose the SQLite database file over the network (for example share it on the network using **Samba** if you are using linux). Another example to access SQLite file is to access the server remotely using **SSH**.

Another better approach is to **program a web service on the server where the SQLite file exists**, and use the API of that web service to CRUD the data from the database.

AFAIK, this is approach i the only possible way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am stuck with sqlite and if I can provide working code, probably can migrate to MySQL or PostGreSQL. Can you please express your opinion on my approach?

Comment: I would be a taker for the web service / CRUD approach. Can you please point me to a link where I can jump-start right away?

Comment: @Harsha, there is nothing in your approach, only as I said, SQLite is not the correct database for that (you see the you cannot directly access it over the network). You can write the web service to CRUD your database using any language. For example I am a .Net Core guy, and I would use it for that, you may change any technology to expose some CRUD functions over the network. So I cannot really provide a link as it depends completely on the language you want to use to expose the CRUD API.